# Android restart thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a thread which starts on the beginning of the activity.
This thread will get some values and then update a textview every 60 seconds.
I need to "kill" the sleep of the thread and restart it immediately if the user clicks on a button.
This is the thread:

```
private void setToNewThread(){
    getValuesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!getValuesThread.isInterrupted()){
                try {
                    final int number = getCurrentNumber();
                    updateUi.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            uiTextNumber.setText("Current number is: " + number);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    getValuesThread.interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

On the onClick event of the button I tried this:

```
if(getValuesThread == null){
    setToNewThread();
    getValuesThread.start();
}else{
    getValuesThread.interrupt();
    getValuesThread = null;
    setToNewThread();
    getValuesThread.start();
}
```

Basically, if the thread is null (which is the default value) the setToNewThread() sets the variable to a new thread, else it stops the one that already exists, sets it to null and creates a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a thread at all.  A timer message posting every 60 seconds would be more efficient.  Unless getCurrentNumber requires significant processing that must be done in parallel, you're losing more time to context switching than you gain via the thread, and complicating your code to boot.

Also your code in the above is wrong due to your interrupted check:

```
while (!getValuesThread.isInterrupted()){
```

You're already in the thread object.  It should be:

```
while(!isInterrupted()){
```

The extra getValuesThread caused it to check the wrong instance.

Comment: How do I change this to a timer? Also, would I be able to kill it and restart it? I never used them

Comment: There's multiple ways to do a timer in android.  One easy way is just to create a Handler and postDelayed to it.  Another is to use Timer and TimerTask.  There's plenty of examples of both online.

Comment: By the way, isInterrupted() didn't work for me, but Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() did

Comment: I missed a ! in my initial code.  That's probably why it didn't work either